# PIG inner join with different keys

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-pig, hcatalog

```
a = LOAD '601' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();

b = LOAD '602' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader(); 

c = LOAD '603' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader(); 

d = LOAD 'SKL' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader(); 

e = join a by (d_key, c_cd ), b by (d_key, c_cd), c by (p1_key, c_cd), d by    (p2_key, c_cd); 

Dump e;
```

========================================================================

If I do the same joins in Hive, I get output. But In Pig, On dumping e, It runs MapReduce, read rows but doesn't write output after success.
But If I do the same thing in hive by nested inner join, I get the correct output.

can anyone explain me the bug in PIG In joining different keys in relations?

Another thing if I want to load with HCatlogue(HCatStore) into a partitioned blank table with dynamic partition (without value). I am getting partitioned table error. I don't know the reason of the error in Hcatalogue.
Please explain me if you faced the same thing and provide me any solution.

Comment: Could you please provide log here.

Comment: I had problems with inner join when I wanted to join three tables. Splitting the single join step into multiple steps was the solution for me. Although it is not desirable, it is worth a try.